# Akka context.parent unexpected value

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, actor, playframework-2.2

The `context.parent` reference does not do it, for me. In a Play project, I launch a new actor to deal with each incoming request:

```
val myActor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor])

val future: Future[String] = (myActor ? Hello)(5.seconds).mapTo[String]

future.map(result => Ok(result)).recover {
  case ex: AskTimeoutException => Ok("timeout expired")
  case _ => Ok("error")
}
```

This triggers more actor messaging in the receive method of `myActor`: when `anotherActor` responds to `myActor`, the latter sends a message `AllGood` to its parent.

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  // other stuff, among which setup of anotherActor

  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case Hallo => anotherActor ! Hello
    case HelloBack => context.parent ! AllGood
  }
}  

class AnotherActor extends Actor {
  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case Hallo => sender ! HelloBack
  }
}
```

Everything works fine until `myActor` tries to send a message to `context.parent`. I get a `deadLetters` message in the console.

```
from Actor[xyz] to Actor[akka://my-system/user] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.
```

I can make it work if `myActor` keeps a reference to the original `sender`, and the code looks like this instead:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  var myDad: Option[ActorRef] = None  // <--- NEW REFERENCE

  // other stuff, among which setup of anotherActor

  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case Hallo => {
      myDad = Some(sender)
      anotherActor ! Hello
    }
    case HelloBack => myDad ! AllGood   <-- MYDAD INSTEAD OF CONTEXT.PARENT
  }
}  

class AnotherActor extends Actor {
  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case Hallo => sender ! HelloBack
  }
}
```

The reference `myDad` is actually something like `Actor[akka://my-system/temp/$a]`, while I would expect it to be the same as the `context.parent` which was `Actor[akka://my-system/user]`. Isn't it the same actor?

Can anybody explain this behaviour to me, and suggest a cleaner way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you mixed up the concepts of parent and sender.

1. context.parent [akka://my-system/user] is normal because the actor has been created as a child of the Akka system using `system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor])`.
2. the sender method gives you back the actor who sent the message. The important thing here is; this is not the actor system who sent the message to your actor. When using the ask pattern Akka creates a temporary actor (in your case `Actor[akka://my-system/temp/$a]`) that will send the message and wait for the answer. When the response is received, the Future is completed.

If you want it is possible to forward the original sender so that your `AnotherActor` can reply directly HelloBack to the temporary actor created by the ask pattern.

To do so just change the way the message is passed to anotherActor.

```
def receive: Actor.Receive = {
case Hallo => anotherActor.tell(Hello, sender)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I see it clear now :)